# Validating ReactJS inputs while using BackboneJS models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I'm creating a form in ReactJS that, upon submit, creates a Backbone model and saves it to my database. Before saving, I'd like validation to occur in the Backbone model and the errors to be presented in the React view. What's the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

#### ReactJS Form View's handleSubmit():

```
handleSubmit: function () {
  var foo = new Foo({
    title: this.state.title,
    description: this.state.description,
    startDate: this.state.startDate,
    endDate: this.state.endDate
  });

  foo.save({
    error: function() {
      console.log("ERROR");
    }
  });
}
```

#### Backbone Model

```
defaults: {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  startDate: "",
  endDate: ""
},

urlRoot: function() {
  return apiUrls("Foo")
}
```

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is asking for a significant amount of code without providing much. The poster is looking for someone else to do the work.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I didn't intend to make it look that way. I'll make an edit with the different ways I'm debating on accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the error message as a state inside the React View:

```
var view = this;
foo.save({
    error: function() {
        view.setState({validationError: 'your error message'});
    },
    success: function() {
        view.setState({validationError: null});
    }
});
```